# How to add a bullet to line number in algorithms

Tags: algorithm2e

I want to add a bullet next to a line number as shown in following picture. How can I get this.

[image]

Comment: Have a look into the `tikzmark` library. If you cannot create it yourself, some dummy code to get us started would be appreciated.

Comment: See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/337633/121799 for an example.

Answer (score 4):

I just copied [some sample code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/359622/121799), used [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/337633/121799) simplify the usage and loaded `tikzpagenodes` to be able to place the star outside the text area to arrive at

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ruled,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,tikzmark}

\newcounter{tmkcount}

\tikzset{use tikzmark/.style={
    remember picture,
    overlay,
    execute at end picture={
      \stepcounter{tmkcount}
    },
  },
  tikzmark suffix={-\thetmkcount}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[ht]
  \SetAlgoLined % from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/359622/121799
  \KwData{this text}
  \KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
  initialization\;
  \While{not at end of this document}{
    read current\;
    \eIf{understand}{
      \tikzmark{star}go to next section\;
      current section becomes this one\;
    }{
      go back to the beginning of current section\;
    }
  }
  \caption{How to write algorithms}
\end{algorithm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[use tikzmark]
\path (pic cs:star) coordinate (aux) 
(current page text area.west|-aux)
node[anchor=east,star,star point ratio=2,draw,fill=yellow,inner sep=.2em,
yshift=.2em]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]